# Parse a large CSV file with two different line formats in Python 2.7 with memory constraints?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pytables, hdfstore

I have a collection of files (one ~10GB file broken into multiple files, so about ~1GB each) that I need to read in Python 2.7.  The file format is like this:

```
1|KEY1|A |B        |01/01/2016|   |
2|KEY1| |LINEINDEX1|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |        |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |        |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   |
2|KEY1| |LINEINDEX2|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |        |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |        |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   
2|KEY1| |LINEINDEX3|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |        |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |        |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   |
2|KEY1| |LINEINDEX4|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |        |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |        |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   |    
1|KEY2|A |B        |01/01/2016|   |
2|KEY2| |LINEINDEX5|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |1       |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |N       |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   |    
2|KEY2| |LINEINDEX6|C            |D  |E                  | 123.000| 456.000| 789.1250|000100000.00|000100000.70|100|01/2016| 001|100|01/2016|050|050|01|001|100|F  |G            |H |1|I|J |   |K  |L    |M  |       |   |   |        |        |   |   |    |        |   |       |   |   |        |        |        |4       |    |             |    |        |                          |  |              |           |   |              |   |   |  |  |        |        |       |   |   |   |   |             |O       |              |   |       |       |   |   |   |   |       |         |   |
```

The line that begins with `2` can repeat indefinitely for unique `LINEINDEX#` values, and then the next line will begin with `1` for a new `KEY` item (followed by its own lines `2`, and so on).  I need to be able to efficiently produce tables of data type `2` based on multiple `KEY`s, so I don't actually need lines `1` at all.  There may or may not be data in the empty fields, so I need to capture everything that's there.

Most of the programs surrounding this data use Pandas, so I was ideally trying to stick to that.  My plan was to parse these files into an HDF5 file, and create the tables from that, as needed.  I'm not sure if that's the best way to deal with the problem at hand, so any suggestions on alternatives are welcome.  Currently, this processing is done in R via ffdf, but it must be moved to Python.

I can't read these files line by line (out of memory pops up almost immediately) to remove/ignore lines `1`.  I tried Pandas `read_csv` with `comment='1'`, to treat these lines as "comments" and ignore them, but I get the CParserError, which seems to be more of a bug than anything based on other posts (I tried skipping the first line as others suggested for that error, but it didn't do the trick).

```
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 504, saw 14
```

If I process the files without specifying the data types (which I have), I get performance issues, e.g.:

```
sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (21) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

Then, when converting `to_hdf`, similar performance issues:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:1138: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot map directly to c-types
```

What is the best way to either ignore lines that begin with `1` all-together, or to somehow specify two different dType maps, without running out of memory, which happens every time I try to work on a line-by-line basis?  Is there a better way to store this data to query for line items `2` based on a list of `KEY`s?

Right now, the code is simply:

```
for input_file in os.listdir(input_path):
            file_path = input_path + '\\' + input_file
            data = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='|')
            data.to_hdf(self.outputs_path + '\converted.h5', 'converted_table')
```

Comment: You will need to post longer samples of your input data - one can't figure out enough of how it is in there, and waht you want to be able to advise you in a meaninful way from your textual description alone. (does the text "LINEINDEX" change or is fixed? Is "KEY" textually repeated on each line? Dows teh cell following "KEY" on non "1" lines contain your desired identifier?

Comment: All in all, the bets advise is to clean up these files, loading then wothut a Data framework and creating a well-behaved CSV file - that you may use in a second pass for your processing needs.

Comment: Please post the code of the attempts you have made so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract any data between the pipes, without spaces, and dump that information into a new file.  It will only write out lines that contain the string `'LINEINDEX'` and if a value between the pipes is all spaces, it is ignored.  If you need to preserve the empty values between the pipes, remove the if clause ( `if x.replace(' ','')` ) from the list comprehension.

```
with open('/path/to/in_file.csv', 'r') as fp:
    with open('/path/to/out_file.csv', 'w') as fp2:
        for line in fp:
            if 'LINEINDEX' in line:
                out = [x.replace(' ','') for x in line.strip().split('|')
                       if x.replace(' ','')]
                fp2.write(','.join(out)+'\n')
```

This should have no memory issues since each file is read and written one at a time, rather than loading the whole files into memory.